# Oracle NoSQL Database I cannot see the JMX statistics in the JConsole

Tags: oracle-nosql

I have an issue when trying to monitor Oracle NoSQL nosql via the jmx interface.

The jmx is active, and I can connect to the jmx interface using jconsole but I can't see the "Oracle NOSQL Database" section in MBeans tab.

We've add the value jmx to mgmt parameter when makebootconfig and our configuration seems ok mgmtClass=oracle.kv.impl.mgmt.jmx.JmxAgent".

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I think that the issue comes from the way that you are using to do the connection in jconsole.

I was able to reproduce the behavior you saw if, in the "New Connection" page on jconsole, I selected a process from the "Local Process" section. In that case, I saw the same list of MBeans, and the NoSQL-specific ones were missing.

I was able to get the correct MBeans by selecting "Remote Process" and specifying the helper hostname and port for the store. In this case, I was using "localhost" and port 5000. When I specified "localhost:5000" in the Remote Process section, then the listed MBeans included the Oracle NoSQL Database ones.

This is well documented https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/20.1/admin/java-management-extensions-jmx.html#GUID-8D151ADE-EC10-446B-8242-1EEC0C3BCB52

Or just run `jconsole localhost:5000` using the good port for your deployment

Hope that this can help you